# RabbitMQ/AMQP Stand Headers and Header Covertions

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I'm trying to find documentation on standard AMQP headers that RabbitMQ uses and ones reserved by the AMQP protocol. I've reviewed the [AMQP documentation](http://www.amqp.org/resources/download) and [RabbitMQ's website](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html) with no luck. Any resources that contain this information? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by headers you mean *message headers*, then search for "These are the properties for a Basic content" here: http://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/specs/amqp0-9-1.extended.xml

Comment: Thank you. I think that part of the problem was that I was conflating "property" and "header". As I understand it, I may implement my own properties, but it is standard practice to use an "application_headers" property that is nothing more than a table of properties from the application that is producing the message.

Comment: yes, you should use `application_headers` for your own headers.